# Problems compiling Bootstrap under windows using grunt

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, npm, windows-8.1

I'm trying to compile Bootstrap under windows. I know I'll have to deal with Jakyll later on, but currently im stuck here:

```
npm install
```

Which leads to an shasum error when it tries to install sauce-tunnel:

```
456 error Error: shasum check failed for C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-884-8iUK1-Qx\1397291845491-0.2589339539408684\tmp.tgz
456 error Expected: 3afd206b6e853cd508d45f92baf323af9d6a6627
456 error Actual:   13cd33918418cf6f1d305bd7daef22c44cf637bc
456 error From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/sauce-tunnel-sc3-1/-/sauce-tunnel-sc3-1-1.0.0.tgz
456 error     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha\index.js:38:8
456 error     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha\index.js:85:7)
456 error     at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
456 error     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
456 error     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
457 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
457 error including the npm and node versions, at:
457 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
458 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
```

I also tried to install it manually

```
npm install https://registry.npmjs.org/sauce-tunnel-sc3-1/-/sauce-tunnel-sc3-1-1.0.0.tgz
```

which only leads to another error:

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Would be superb, if you could help!

Update: I forgot the Versions:

```
Node: v0.10.26
NPM: 1.4.3
Bootstrap : Git master (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git)
```

Comment: Which versions of node, npm, and bootstrap are you using? For bootstrap it would also be good to know which repository you got it from.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, @JasonAller - I added the information.